# Look up property by name using a string variable

Tags: javascript

I want to look up a property of a Javascript object using a string inside of a variable, but when I execute the code below, the second alert returns `undefined`.

```
 <script>
    var operations = {"Create": "POST",
                      "Read": "GET",
                      "Delete": "DELETE"
    };
    //result POST
    alert(operations.Create);

    var method="Create";
    alert(operations.method); //returns undefined, I want it to return "POST"
 </script>
```

How do I use the "`method`" variable to look up the "`Create`" property I created at the beginning of the script?

Comment: 100 times a day. Anyone find any dupes?

Comment: What do you expect from your script?

Comment: (The original question has been edited to clarify the author's problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

`operations[method]`

you can't use dot notation if you want to access by a variable.  The reason is when you use dot notation, the interpreter is not using the value of the variable; it thinks the variable name itself is the key.  In other words, it's looking for the key "method", not "Create".

Answer (score 0):

Method is not defined in your object declaration so it is doing what it should.  var method is not contained within the ooerations.  you want to define.

Answer (score 0):

`Operations` does not have a method property. If you wanted to add that value to your object, you could do this:

```
operations.method = "Create";
alert(operations.method);
```

If you want to get the value for a specific string key, you can look it up by the indexer:

```
alert(operations["Create"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
var method=operations.Create;
alert(method);
```

or

```
var method="Create";
alert(operations[method]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're declaring method as a separate string object. Instead of

```
var method="Create";
```

try doing

```
operations.method = "Create";
```

This will make **method** an actual property of the **operations** object, which you will be able to access either from **operations.method** or **operations["method"]**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var operations = {"Create" : "POST",
                  "Read" : "GET",
                  "Delete" : "DELETE"
                };

alert(operations.Create);

operations.method = 'Create';
alert(operations.method);

var method = 'Create';
alert(method);
```